# Transaction errors in JBoss AS 7.1 with MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, transactions

Sometimes it occurs some errors in my web application, these errors makes my application very slow and the first end up generating other errors.

Usually the regular application runs with 100 + users, sometimes it happens less.

This usually occurs a few days after starting the server.

When the problem occurs, I try to restart the jboss and mysql but the application back slowly.

Some characteristics of the application:

Constant database access (An example is checking for new messages in chat, for each user is checked every 10-60 seconds if there is a new message)

- We have an average of 30 users online and may even reach 300.
- We use Amazon AWS server (m.large)
- We use a Controller architecture -> Business -> DAO

Here are a few lines from the error log generated by Jboss:

> 14:33:19,450 WARN [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper)
>   ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX
>   0:ffffac1f18d6:69031402:540ce9d8:8c88e1 in state RUN
>
> 14:33:19,543 WARN [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker
>   0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id
>   0:ffffac1f18d6:69031402:540ce9d8:8c88e1 invoked while multiple threads
>   active within it.
>
> 14:33:19,544 WARN [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker
>   0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action
>   0:ffffac1f18d6:69031402:540ce9d8:8c88e1 aborting with 1 threads
>   active!
>
> 14:33:19,977 WARN [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper)
>   ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX
>   0:ffffac1f18d6:69031402:540ce9d8:8c88e1 in state CANCEL
>
> 14:33:20,503 WARN [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper)
>   ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX
>   0:ffffac1f18d6:69031402:540ce9d8:8c88e1 in state CANCEL_INTERRUPTED
>
> 14:33:20,513 WARN [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper)
>   ARJUNA012120: TransactionReaper::check worker Thread[Transaction
>   Reaper Worker 0,5,main] not responding to interrupt when cancelling TX
>   0:ffffac1f18d6:69031402:540ce9d8:8c88e1 -- worker marked as zombie and
>   TX scheduled for mark-as-rollback
>
> 14:33:20,517 WARN [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper)
>   ARJUNA012110: TransactionReaper::check successfuly marked TX
>   0:ffffac1f18d6:69031402:540ce9d8:8c88e1 as rollback only
>
> 14:33:26,037 WARN [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper)
>   ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX
>   0:ffffac1f18d6:69031402:540ce9d8:8c8a92 in state RUN
>
> 14:33:45,711 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-93)
>   JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component business/MensagemBS for
>   method public abstract java.util.List
>   br.com.coderpro.business.local.MensagemBSLocal.getMensagensRecebidasDoUsuario(java.lang.Long,br.com.coderpro.entities.TipoUsuario)
>   throws br.com.coderpro.exceptions.BusinessException:
>   javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
>   at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:115)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:95)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:232)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at
>   br.com.coderpro.business.local.MensagemBSLocal$$$view165.getMensagensRecebidasDoUsuario(Unknown
>   Source) [classes:] at
>   br.com.coderpro.services.ConsultaService.listarMensagens(ConsultaService.java:200)
>   [classes:] at
>   br.com.coderpro.services.ConsultaService$Proxy$_$$WeldClientProxy.listarMensagens(ConsultaService$Proxy$$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
>   [classes:] at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor452.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) [:1.7.0_51] at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51] at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:155)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:] at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:] at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:] at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:] at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:] at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:] at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:] at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:] at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:] at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:] at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at
>   org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
>   [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at
>   br.com.coderpro.controller.filters.KeepMeLoggedInFilterController.doFilter(KeepMeLoggedInFilterController.java:64)
>   [classes:] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51] Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException:
>   ARJUNA016063: The transaction is not active! at
>   com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1155)
>   at
>   com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:117)
>   at
>   com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
>   at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:92)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] ... 56 more
>
> 15:11:16,316 ERROR [br.com.coderpro.dao.ProjetoDAO]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-112)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException:
>   Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
>   15:11:16,315 ERROR [br.com.coderpro.dao.ProjetoDAO]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-252)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException:
>   Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
>   15:11:16,315 ERROR [br.com.coderpro.dao.ProjetoDAO]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-369)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException:
>   Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
>   15:11:16,815 ERROR [br.com.coderpro.business.ProjetoBS]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-252) br.com.coderpro.exceptions.DAOException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException:
>   Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
>   15:11:16,241 WARN [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper)
>   ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX
>   0:ffffac1f18d6:69031402:540ce9d8:8ee30a in state RUN

Summarizing are errors [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna], errors in bs classes and dao (Transaction rolled back Caused by The transaction is not active!) And also some deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any bean-managed transactions? Look for "UserTransaction" references in your code. Your stack trace mentions "CMTTxInterceptor" so there may be some container-managed transactions involved (they are the default for beans in J-boss).

I've seen this symptom when both container and bean-managed transaction beans were mixed. Some Oracle documentation mentioned it was unsupported; though, I can't find it at present. At times my arrangement worked fine, but when timeouts came up or other unexpected errors occurred it would fail in this and other troublesome ways.

EDIT: If both bean and container-managed are in use then go with one or the other.